# Typescript Object doesn't support property or method open

Tags: typescript, vue.js, contextmenu, vue-context-menu

I use context menu in vue. Code is written in typescript.

```
 <div
        v-for="(color, index) in colors"
        class="colored-box"
        :style="{background: color}"
        @click="sayColor(color)"
        @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.ctx.open($event, {color: color, index: index})">
    </div>

    <context-menu id="testingctx" ref="ctx" @ctx-open="onCtxOpen" @ctx-cancel="resetCtxLocals" @ctx-close="onCtxClose">
      <li class="ctx-header">kkkk</li>
      <li class="ctx-item">option one</li>
      <li class="ctx-item disabled">option two (disabled)</li>
      <li class="ctx-item">add to log</li>
    </context-menu>
```

The sample is taken from project site.
Error displays when I click right button of the mouse:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'open'
```

Comment: The error message is self explanatory don't you think? I am not sure what your actual question is.

Comment: why self explanatory? here is the error: $refs.ctx.open($event, but I don't understand why method open is no available in typescript

Comment: Is this the context-menu you are using? [vue-context-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-context-menu)

Comment: Yes, this is the context-menu. This code I have in Vue template in typescript file

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your reply comment until now. I tried out vmaimone's sample myself, but could not get the error. Here is the test environment, may help you [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xnpjkm51n)

Comment: I moved code from cshtml file to vue component template and now it works, I don't know why this code won't work when it's placed in cshtml code but never mind